# how to set the environment variable ANT_OPTS in ubuntu?

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, liferay, liferay-ide

while setting up liferay environment in Ubuntu 10.0.4, i have set the environment variables like this in .bashrc file

```
PATH=/usr/bin/java/jdk1.7.0_51/bin:$PATH
export PATH

JAVA_HOME=/usr/bin/java/jdk1.7.0_51
export JAVA_HOME

PATH=/usr/bin/ant/bin:$PATH
export PATH

ANT_HOME=/usr/bin/ant

export ANT_HOME

ANT_OPTS="-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m"

export ANT_OPTS

set path=$path $ANT_HOME/bin
```

i have tested environment variables like this  in my terminal:

```
sudheer@VY-B3:~$ echo $PATH
/usr/bin/ant/bin:/usr/bin/java/jdk1.7.0_51/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
sudheer@VY-B3:~$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/bin/java/jdk1.7.0_51
sudheer@VY-B3:~$ echo $ANT_HOME
/usr/bin/ant
sudheer@VY-B3:~$ echo $ANT_OPTS
-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
```

while running build-themes for liferay  getting following error:

```
Buildfile: /home/sudheer/Desktop/Life-ray/Liferay_workspace/portal/portal-web/build.xml

BUILD FAILED
/home/sudheer/Desktop/Life-ray/Liferay_workspace/portal/portal-web/build.xml:4: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/sudheer/Desktop/Life-ray/Liferay_workspace/portal/build-common-web.xml:4: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/sudheer/Desktop/Life-ray/Liferay_workspace/portal/build-common.xml:393: .

Please set the environment variable ANT_OPTS to the recommended value of
"-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m".

Total time: 2 seconds
```

Comment: `set path=$path $ANT_HOME/bin` <-- uhm, that does not look legal...

Comment: means do i have to remove it?

Comment: @ASR Do you run ant from the command line or from eclipse?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

lastly i have stetted the environment variables like this:

```
# Java environment variables

JAVA_HOME=/opt/java/jdk1.7.0_51
export JAVA_HOME

PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
export PATH


ANT_HOME=/opt/apache-ant-1.7.1
export ANT_HOME

PATH=$ANT_HOME/bin:$PATH 
export PATH 

ANT_OPTS="-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m"
export ANT_OPTS
```

in the .bashrc file, i have opened the eclipse in terminal.. now its working fine..

Answer (score 3):

I see several problems in your .bashrc

- `/usr/bin/java/jdk1.7.0_51/bin` doesn't look right. `/usr/bin` is for executable files. Usually this is something like `/usr/lib/java/...` or `/usr/lib/jvm/...`
- same for `JAVA_HOME` and `ANT_HOME`
- @fge already pointed to `set path=$path $ANT_HOME/bin`. This would be rather `PATH=$PATH:$ANT_HOME/bin`

And finally the error message, the only difference is just `512m` vs `256m`.

*Update:*

I just looked in my system (Ubuntu 12.04), ant is located below `/usr/share/ant`, so for ant this would be

```
ANT_HOME=/usr/share/ant
```

Although, if you installed the ant package via package management, there should be no need to set `ANT_HOME` and `PATH`.

*Update:*

If you run ant from eclipse, .bashrc might not be loaded, unless you start eclipse from the command line. .bashrc is only loaded for an interactive bash shell, see [Bash Startup Files](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Startup-Files)

Comment: changed from path=$path $ANT_HOME/bin to PATH=$PATH:$ANT_HOME/bin still getting same error

Comment: These two are unrelated, I only wanted to point out some problematic parts. For the error message, you must only change 256 to 512.

Comment: @ASR So what problem remains? The situation you mention just demands to change 256 to 512. You should either have a working system now (then please accept this answer) or run into a different problem. In that case, please edit the question or ask a new question with the new error message